# VBA function - How to set function parameter type as criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a function `searchRow` to get the row for target value.

For the parameter `value`, How to set this parameter as a criteria? So I can use the function in excel like `searchRow(<3, A1:A100)`, instead of only value like `searchRow(10, A1:A100)`

```
Function searchRow(value As String, targetRange As range) As Double
    
    Dim currentRange As range
    
    For Each currentRange In targetRange.Cells
        If currentRange.value = value Then
            searchRow = currentRange.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentRange
    
End Function
```

Comment: If using `<`: Is `targetRange` sorted? Do you want to return the first result that is lower than 3 (e.g. 1 in 1,2,3) - or the one closest to 3 (e.g. 2 in 1,2,3)?

Answer (score 6):

You could leverage `Worksheet.Evaluate` here, and complete the expression at each iteration to evaluate it in the context of that worksheet:

```
Public Function SearchRow(ByVal Value As Variant, ByVal TargetRange As Range) As Variant

    If IsError(Value) Then
        SearchRow = Value
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim Context As Worksheet
    Set Context = TargetRange.Parent

    Dim CurrentRange As Range

    Dim ValueExpression As String
    Dim ExpressionResult As Variant

    Dim Operators As Variant
    Operators = Array("<", "<=", "=", "!=", "=>", ">")

    Dim LocalValue As String
    Dim ValueString As String
    Dim HasOperator As Boolean
    
    For Each CurrentRange In TargetRange.Cells

        LocalValue = Value
        ValueString = CurrentRange.Value
        ValueExpression = vbNullString
        ExpressionResult = Empty
        HasOperator = False

        Dim CurrentOperator As Long
        For CurrentOperator = LBound(Operators) To UBound(Operators)
            If Len(ValueString) > Len(CurrentOperator) Then
                If Left$(ValueString, Len(CurrentOperator)) = CurrentOperator Then
                    HasOperator = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next

        'if there's no operator, assume equals and still evaluate:
        If Not HasOperator And IsNumeric(Value) Then LocalValue = "=" & Value
        
        If ValueString <> vbNullString Then
            ValueExpression = ValueString & LocalValue
        
            On Error Resume Next
            ExpressionResult = CBool(Context.Evaluate(ValueExpression))
            On Error GoTo 0
        
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                SearchRow = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                Exit Function
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(ExpressionResult) Then
                'now we know the result is safe to meaningfully treat as a Boolean:
                If ExpressionResult Then
                    SearchRow = CurrentRange.Row
                    Exit Function
                End If

            End If

        End If
    Next CurrentRange
    SearchRow = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Note how the `Variant` return type can be leveraged to yield somewhat meaningful error codes to the worksheet.

Since the first parameter is a `String` we need to enclose the first argument with double quotes when we mean to give it a *string literal*, so usage looks like `=SearchRow("<3",A1:A100)`, but could just as well deal with `42` or `SomeNamedRange`, and would fail pretty much the way `SUM` does given an error value in the inputs.